# In English, noun phrases within a relative clause cannot be further relativized, but this is allowed in some cases in Japanese

Tags: syntax, grammar, relative-clauses

[Japanese: Revised edition](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39551/16344) by Shoichi Iwasaki:

> In English, noun phrases within a relative clause cannot be further relativized, but this is allowed in some cases in Japanese.

If there is  such a rule for English, it must hold for many other Western languages.  (I thought nesting was straightforward.)

What is the rule?

It seems to be related to Accessibility.  See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Accessibility_hierarchy

Comment: This is obviously wrong. "This is the cat that killed the rat that ate the malt that lay in the house that Jack built."

Comment: That seems wrong. Could you give an example?

Comment: @TKR - your sample is not nested.  This is: "The rat that the cat that Jack has was eaten."

Comment: @aml The question as stated seems to be whether NPs in a relative clause can themselves be relativized (i.e. be the antecedent of a relative clause), which they are in the example I gave. But this may be a bad formulation (see Greg Lee's answer).

Answer (score 9):

Iwasaki's formulation is unclear.  What he means is that besides the one NP in a relative clause that is made into a relative pronoun (or ortherwise marked as being relativized), you cannot relativize a second NP in the same relative clause.  For instance, relativizing "the book" in "John gave the book to the girl" gives the relative clause "which John gave to the girl".  If you then try to relativize "the girl" in this relative clause, you get the unacceptable *"who(m) ... which John gave to".

For instance, *"the girl who(m) I read the book which John gave to" has had two relative pronouns removed from the clause "John gave [] to []".  Evidently this is prohibited.  John Ross in **Constraints on Variables in Syntax** studied such cases, compared the English examples with Japanese examples, and concluded that the Complex NP Constraint, as he dubbed it, applies only to "chopping rules" and not to "copying rules".  With chopping rules, nothing is left in the original position of a relative pronoun, while something may be left behind by a copying rule.

Comment: @HizHa Don't ask people to delete their answers. You can anonymize this question by disassociating your account from it, your username will disappear from this site.

Comment: Dear Mr. Lee. Thank you for your comments. I've saved multiple copies of your comments, and i may be learning things from them years from now. _________ I have a request. Could you delete your answer? I am trying to retreat (scale back my presence)  from Ling.SE and would like to delete this page. After you've deleted your answer, i should be able to delete the other answers and the original question. Thank you very much for your consideration. –

Comment: ( Just above, a moderator tells me, "... your username will disappear from this site." ---- but that is not what i want to see happen. _______  So therefore, Prof. Lee, (I ask you) please delete this answer. Thank you very much for your consideration. )

Comment: Prof. Lee, if it is a strict requirement, I will try to present to you some of the reasons why this is so important to me. _______ ( I thought that your comment was reasonable and informative, but it apparently had a profound, unitended effect on some people here.  When you declared that [ Iwasaki's formlation is unclear. ],  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ) _______ But I'm still hoping that you will respect my wishes before requiring any further explanation.

Comment: _______ ( . . . your comment had a profound effect on some people. When you wrote [ Iwasaki's formlation is unclear. What he means is that ... ], some people took that as your declaration that Japanese people have a fundamental deficiency and a severe understanding problem regarding such matters, and that the Japanese (Iwasaki, me, ...)  ___needed help___ in explaining what they mean, because the Japanese can't do it themselves, being disabled by that understanding problem. ) __________ But I'm still hoping that you will respect my wishes before requiring any further explanation.

Comment: Prof. Lee, -- I just had an idea -- your comments (the answer) would be preserved if I quoted it in Jp.SE, or if you posted it there (in Jp.SE).  I'm sure your comments would be appreciated and admired there.  After that, this page (the question) can be deleted.  Does this make any sense at all?  Thank you.

Comment: @HizHa Maybe I wasn't clear: **you won't lose your account on this site**. Only the question won't show your username, but you'll still possess your account *and* you'll be able to post questions.

Comment: @HizHa The problem with asking Greg Lee to delete his answer is that he put effort into writing it that could be of use to other people besides yourself. What Alenanno is suggesting will mean that this question is no longer attached to your account in any way; your account will be shown as never having asked or interacted with this question. That's a good middle ground that lets you remove the association with this question that you're trying to, and it lets Greg Lee and the rest of the community keep this good answer around for future reference.

Comment: Then a good idea may be for the Prof to ask a question and answer it himself. -- he's done it before. ______ (Or I'd certainly be willing to ask another, similar question, from a new account.)  ___________ (The question should prob. be very short. It should not make any direct or indirect refs to me or to anything I've written.) ____________ After that, this page (the question) can be deleted.

Comment: @ArtOfCode -- Hi. thanks for the comment, but you've told me nothing I didn't know before. ________________ My intention was always to move Prof Lee's answer somewhere else. (or have it moved, or have him move it, .... ) __________________The "anonymizing" procedure that the moderator was suggesting has several huge disadvantages for me -- I've listed 3 of these in the Ling SE chat. The moderator  is (I think) beginning to see why the "anonymizing" procedure has no benefits for me, only huge disadvantages. Thanks.

Comment: Could you copy your  answer [ Iwasaki's formulation is unclear. ............... ] to your new question page (either as an appendix to the question or another answer, etc.), and delete this earlier answer? _______________________ Now that the moderator(s) see that the only "solution" they were suggesting (anonymizing to make my username disappear) had absolutely no merits or advantages for me, this should be more acceptable. Thank you very much.